# Multiple save on upload plus save on database errors

Tags: php

I have set of questions have you ever encounter some issues when multiple save on database?my problem is this, i have a database called "album" where fields are 'album_id,album_title,album_user'.

The html output would be there is a login section where there is a input type file where you want to add more and once you have uploaded it. and array of set of names will be stored and that array will be our que to save the file on the multiple format the problem is that. it says and error on the database whichs is sql specified twice.Do you have an idea on how to save in multiple using php?

code will be like this.

```
    <?php
class Album extends olib{

    function __construct(){
        parent::olib();
    }       

    function upload_submit() {
        $allow = array("jpg","png","gif");
        $directory = "upload";
        $pictures = array();
        $counter = 0;
        $error = '';
        if($this->jpost('upload')) {
            for($getupload = 0;$getupload<count($_FILES['uploadpictures']['name']);$getupload++){           
                $extension = end(explode(".",$_FILES['uploadpictures']['name'][$getupload]));
                if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$allow)){
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadpictures']['tmp_name'][$getupload],$directory."/".$_FILES['uploadpictures']['name'][$getupload])){
                        $pictures[$getupload] = $_FILES['uploadpictures']['name'][$getupload];
                        $counter++;
                    //  $this->save_user_album($_FILES['uploadpictures']['name'][$getupload],$this->setSession('user_id'));
                    }else{
                        $error[$getupload] = "Sorry seems some of the data invalid";
                    }
                }else{
                    $error = '1';
                }
            }       
            print_r($pictures);
            print_r($error);
            foreach($pictures as $urpics){
                $this->save_user_album($urpics,$this->setSession('user_id'));
            }
        }
    }


    function save_user_album($albumtitle,$session){
        $_firewall = ($this->setSession('user_id') !=="") ? $this->setSession('user_id') : "";  
            $this->jfields('album_pics_title',$albumtitle);
        //  $this->jfields('album_pics_user',$session);
        return $this->jSave('album_pics');
    }




}
```

any response will greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hard to say what's going on, because you're using some libraries and classes. Post error messages you get, and also, post the output of `print_r` it may be helpful

Comment: example this will be the output

$picture = array("a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg");
  foreach($picture as $pic):  
    save_here($pic);  
  endforeach;

but the only problem is that when it loads and error occur which is
'album_title' specified twice.these error will error if my the users input file has uploaded too many pictures...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm sorry seems i have a solution for this i have unset after it has been save..
`unset($this->jfields);` problem has been solved